# how to extract html data using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

HTML data can be extracted using perl in following manner...

```
my $URL= "http://10.20.100.34/cgi-bin/usage.pl?server=server1";
my $content = get($URL);
print $content;
```

Can it be done using javascript? If yes, how??

Comment: what do you mean by html data?

Comment: i want to extract information abt servers from different url's and put them in one page and keep updating that page using ajax.